# If we have a backup for all the sharepoint 2013 databases, can/how we restore a corrupted application server

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, restore, database

One of our customers use to have a sharepoint enterprise farm 2013, with the following architecture:-

1. windows 2008 R2 which contain sharepoint on-premises farm 2013.
2. windows 2008 R2 which contain Sql Server.

Our customer was backup-ing the sharepoint databases on daily basis, while the sharepoint application server was not backup-ed or even tracked. and the application server had a sever damage and they could not restore it. so now our customer have a full backup for all the sharepoint databases including; content database, managed metadata databases, configuration database, etc...

But per my knowledge is that to be able to integrate a new sharepoint farm with existing databases, the farm need to be on the same farm build number + have the same sharepoint patches installed as the source farm... but in our customer case these info (farm build number + patches involved) are not available.

So i have these 2 questions:-

1. Is there a way from the databases' backups we have to build a new farm which works on these databases?
2. Now our customer have a valid license for sharepoint and the windows server, so can we open a ticket with Microsoft regarding this? and will Microsoft cover such scenarios? where we need to build a new SharePoint farm which work on existing databases?

Answer (score 1):

You can define SharePoint  build version by executing SQL query on SharePoint config db.

```
SELECT Version, TimeStamp FROM Versions     

WHERE VersionId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'   

ORDER BY Id DESC
```

After that you can install SharePoint with necessary CU and restore dbs.

Comment: now i am not sure if knowing the build version is sufficient/enough to do a valid Backup/restore or a full recovery for the farm. as in sharepoint 2013, we can reach a farm version by installing a full CU or just a simple security update. so we might have 2 sharepoint farms which have the exact build number but they reached the build number from different sharepoint updates, and as a result we will not be able to not backup/restore the farm on these 2 SP farms even if they have the same version number. so not sure if your sql query will be helpful in our case,, or i am missing something?

Comment: Just install the CU with the same build number. That will be sufficient.

Comment: @TrevorSeward but in our case they do NOT install full CU very frequent, what they did is that around 3 years ago they installed a full CU as it contain many fixes to problems they use to have, then after that each couple of months they install sharepoint security updates only (as part of their security policy) >> run the product configuration wizard >> and this caused their farm build number to increment, so their current farm build number was not reached from a full CU but rather from sharepoint security updates..

Comment: @TrevorSeward ..so it does not matter? what matters is the farm build number we got from the sql query `SELECT Version, TimeStamp FROM Versions     

WHERE VersionId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'   

ORDER BY Id DESC`,, regardless if it was reached from a full CU or from some sharepoint security updates?

Comment: It does not matter. If build versions are the same - it will be possible to restore your dbs on new env with the same build number.

Comment: @Raf this what the logic says ,, but when you read link such as https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/ which says that `SharePoint does not have a build version. Full Stop.` you got confused.. So you are saying that what really matters is the farm build number regardless of how we reach it.. is this correct?

Comment: Don't get wrapped up in the details. Just install the CU that matches the current build number (or greater). You don't have to hunt down each security patch that way.

Comment: @TrevorSeward now let me summarize my real problem , our customer had their SP 2013 application server crashed.. and they were not backup-ing it, but they have a full backup of their sharepoint databases.. now when i run the sql query `SELECT Version, TimeStamp FROM Versions  WHERE VersionId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'   ORDER BY Id DESC` i got this number `15.0.4787.1000`..

Comment: @TrevorSeward ....but based on the customer feedback is that this farm build number was reached from sharepoint security updates and not from a full CU. so now i can install a brand new sharepoint 2013 farm on a new windows server >> chose to work with the existing databases >> then install the January 2016 CU which represtns their farm build number.. is this  a valid appraoch to try?

Comment: Your customer was right not to backup a SharePoint Server. They're disposable and cannot be restored from a VM backup anyways. Just install a full CU. By the way, your customer has been out of support for the past year - https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2017/12/13/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok i see, in this case after we have the farm up and running again, will inform them to install the latest CU, of course this will need extra testing from their side. second point, as i did not do this step before, if we want to install a new sharepoint farm , can i connect it with existing databases?

Comment: Yes, it can given those databases are not attached to another farm.

Comment: @TrevorSeward they are still attached to the same farm,, but the application server need to be replaced.. so can i follow these general steps:- 1) create a new windows server 2008 R2 VM >> Install sharepoint enterprise farm 2013 with SP1 >> chose to connect the new sharepoint farm with existing databases (i assume this step will be done during the installation) >> after the instillation is done >> install the January 2016 CU ?? are those steps valid, and can be tested? or i am missing something?

Comment: No, after you create the new server with SP1 + new CU, I would bump the existing servers up to the same supported CU (keep in mind, most 2013 CUs are just a collection of security fixes at this point in the product lifecycle). Then run the config wizard on the existing servers. Finally, join the new server to the farm.

Comment: @TrevorSeward now i do not want to mix things together ,, first step is that i want to have the sharepoint running again with their old farm build number `15.0.4787.1000`.. then i will install a supported CU.. so to have our `15.0.4787.1000` running again what are the steps which I need to follow? as in your reply you mentioned to create a new sharepoint with new databases? i thought i will be installing a new sharepoint and chose to connect to existing DBs instead of creating new DBs...can you elaborate more on this please?

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you please advice on my above comment.. thanks

Comment: You'd need to install each and every patch you applied to the old server to the new one. That won't be fun, but it is do-able. You'll need to look in the old server's Add/Remove Programs to view the update history. If you don't do that, then you just need to install the same or newer CU.

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok this point is clear to me.. but i mean how i need to create a brand new sharepoint? i am planning to do these steps >> install a new SP inside a new VM using the `SharePointServer_x64_en-us.img` >> install SP1 >> run the product configuration wizard >> create new web application >> install January 2016 CU which represents `15.0.4787.1000` >> so in this case i will have a brand new sharepoint farm with 2 web applications (central admin + web application) + empty managed services (search, managed emtadta, etc). But how i can force those components to use our backup-ed databases?